# Inherited Resources and Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inherited-resources, draper

How to use [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) with [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)?

In other words, how to call the method(`#decorate`) for each resource? For example `@posts` for `#index`, `@post` for `#show`?

I thought about `default_scope`, but everything related with Draper needs to be in the controller, not in the model, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look to this discussion in Draper's Github:

https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/99